# zmodem crashing with large files over TCP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, file-transfer, serial-port

I'm attempting to send files to a Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3+ from a Windows 10 PC using a UART-WiFi bridge; the Pi is connected to the UART side, the PC connects to the bridge via WiFi. The bridge is the only possible form of interface with the Pi without serious project modifications. I've successfully transferred small (~3-5kB) files, both text and binary, using TeraTerm's ZMODEM functionality, but if I try to send anything larger, even in the order of tens of kilobytes, the ZMODEM transfer hangs, and eventually I will either get 'file xyz removed', a garbage file, or nothing.

With a 13kB file, the progress bar reaches 100% and the number of bytes transferred appears correct, but it will still fail, while with significantly larger files in the megabyte range, the progress bar will only reach a certain value then hang/flicker. This value appears constant for any one file, ie every time I attempt to send the file it will reach the same figure, but varies between files significantly.

The larger files I've tried to send have been random Excel spreadsheets and .stl files I had lying around on my desktop if that's relevant. Any idea what the problem might be? I suspected a poor connection, but after upgrading the antenna on the UART-WiFi bridge (an ESP8266), the progress bar still reached exactly the same value before hanging. I might suspect a special character throwing a spanner in the works, but I would have thought ZMODEM resilient against that kind of thing. There's definitely enough space for all the files, as I recently deleted a massive 33GB video stream file.

Comment: Back in the day we used Kermit when Zmodem transfer failed on my 2400 baud modem. Looks like you can run `gkermit` on a RaspberryPi. Try that out. Also make sure all of your serial settings are correct. You've got a lot of moving parts in between.

Comment: @HackSlash the serial settings match, but they're up at 115200 baud - is that quite high for zmodem?

Comment: Depends on the quality of the connection. I'm not sure what sort of noise you get on a wireless link like yours With physical cables the length and the shielding properties can affect the max speed without error. Turning the speed down allows for longer cables, more noise in the system. It's certainly worth a try at19200, and 9600 bps.

Comment: @HackSlash I did indeed get Kermit to succeed where zmodem is failing, but at around 300 baud it's not particularly practical for sending tens of megabytes on a daily basis - fiddling with the bitrate seemed to help zmodem, but whenever it reaches the end of a larger file it will keep looping back to the same point in the progress bar or just hang

Comment: To clarify, kermit was transmitting at approximately 300 bits per second with a serial baud rate of 19200

Comment: Ok, now read this article about improving kermit speeds: http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/faq-c-zmo.html

Answer (score 1):

I've seen similar problems before. It may be the case that your bridge, or the drivers on the PC side, are misconfigured or incapable of honoring flow control from your devices UART. Your bridge software might allow to configure simulated hardware flow control, if you're lucky.

Some of the old *Modem transfer programs allowed you some control over packet size and/or a delay period between packets. They also let you enable/disable wire level flow control and set a number of other pacing parameters, like adding some delay between characters.

Serial to X bridges often get confused when the device on the serial side invokes hardware flow-control, which is something it might do when it's got a block of data to write to another device, and needs to prevent serial interrupts for a while.

It's been a couple of decades since I last worked with ZModem, but I think you can configure the PC side, to introduce delay between packets, and configure the Pi side to not use hardware flow control. I seem to recall there's also a sliding window size you can configure, but I might be confusing that with one of the other *Modem programs.

You'll just have to RTM and experiment. Keep in mind that ZModem has a 4GiB file size limit, due to it using 32 bit file offsets when the receiver requests dropped packets. I suppose that could go much longer, if there's no dropped packets during the transfer, and the implementation doesn't prevent you from attempting it.